# How to skip autonumber field while using insert into

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I have created a table in Microsoft Access with these fields:

```
ID | Time | Roll_no | Attendance
```

where `ID` is default auto-number field.

I am trying to use the following code but it's generating this error:

```
"java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."
```

Code:

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into co3gs(Time, Roll_no, Attendance) values(?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1,mytime);
ps.setString(2,r1);
ps.setString(3,P);
```

Comment: Can you give examples of `mytime`, `r1`, and `P`?

Comment: mytime="10:30:51 PM";r1="201";P="AB"; all are string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TIME is a reserved word: [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx); try to rename that column in the database table (and of course update your query).

Comment: Some square braces around it would be fine as well: `insert into co3gs([Time], ...`